# Get Portlet Application Context from another portlet (Liferay + Spring)

Tags: java, spring, liferay, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I want to create a portlet (let's call it 'Action Manager') to list all the action methods (using spring Annotation `@ActionMapping`) from all the portlets in the same page as my Action Manager portlet.

All my other portlets are using `ParameterHandlerMapping` to map the incoming requests to the appropriate Controller

```
<bean id="parameterHandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.portlet.handler.ParameterHandlerMapping">
    <property name="defaultHandler" ref="Controller1" />
    <property name="parameterName" value="control" />
    <property name="parameterMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="1" value-ref="Controller1" />
            <entry key="2" value-ref="Controller2" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So my intention is to get all the portlets in my current page (I'm already doing that) and try to get the `parameterHandlerMapping` bean from each portlet and, from there, get its controller names (`Controller1`, `Controller2`) which I will later used to get the `@ActionMapping` annotated methods.

Is it possible to access each portlet "private" context and retrieve the `parameterHandlerMapping` bean?

I'm currently stuck with this:

```
PortletBag portletBag = PortletBagPool.get(portlet.getPortletId());
    if (portletBag != null) {
        ServletContext servletContext = portletBag.getServletContext();
        ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
        ParameterHandlerMapping parameterHandlerMapping = (ParameterHandlerMapping) ctx.getBean(ParameterHandlerMapping.class);

}
```

This results in an exception being thrown because there's no matching bean in the application context. I tried to get it by the bean's name and the result is pretty much the same.

I also got a list of all the beans present in the context using

```
String beanNames[] = ctx.getBeanNamesForType(Object.class);
for (String beanName : beanNames) {
    System.out.println(beanName);
}
```

and the `parameterHandlerMapping` bean is not present.

It's my understanding that each portlet has its own `parameterHandlerMapping` bean, so i guess  the `ctx` i'm getting is the "global" context and not the portlet's own "private" context where the `parameterHandlerMapping` bean is defined.

If I'm correct and I'm getting the "global" context, is there a way to get a portlet's "private" context based on its portletId? Is it even possible to do what I want?

Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

You could use the:

```
com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.PortletBeanLocatorUtil.getBeanLocator("portlet-context-name")
```

to get a BeanLocator object for each portlet you want by giving the context-name of each one of them. 
From there, you could use the:

```
locator.locate("bean-id")
```

passing the id of the bean, to get the bean you want.

However, you need to be sure that all these portlets are deployed in the server otherwise you will probably get an exception. A way to ensure this, is to declare these portlets as required contexts for your Action Manager portlet in its liferay plugin package properties, ensuring this way that the Action Manager portlet will not be deployed unless all the other portlets are already deployed in the web server.

p.s. I am referring to Liferay version 6.0